# QtOpengl conflict with Opengl framwork on mac

Tags: qt, opengl

I am trying to merge cocos2d-x 3.12 and Qt 5.7 together and was keep getting the conflict error message when linking:

```
In file included from Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Headers/QGLWidget:1:
In file included from Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Headers/qgl.h:45:
In file included from Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/qopengl.h:124:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl3.h:2704:21: error: conflicting types for 'glDepthRange'
GLAPI void APIENTRY glDepthRangef (GLclampf n, GLclampf f);
                    ^
demo/cocos2d-x/cocos/platform/mac/CCGL-mac.h:43:41: note: expanded from macro 'glDepthRangef'
#define glDepthRangef                   glDepthRange
                                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl3.h:1662:21: note: previous declaration is here
GLAPI void APIENTRY glDepthRange (GLclampd near, GLclampd far);
```

I tried to remove the Opengl Framework in .pro file like this :

```
QT       += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = QtApplication
TEMPLATE = app

#INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
#LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lGLEW
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lz
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lcurl

LIBS    += -framework Cocoa
LIBS    += -framework Foundation
LIBS    += -framework OpenAL
LIBS    += -framework IOKit
LIBS    += -framework CoreVideo
LIBS    += -framework OpenGL
```

But it was not working, still the same error.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Looks like a Qt bug, but you really need to show a minimal `main.cpp` that reproduces it, too.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this error arises due to Qt's policy of overwriting OpenGL-related macro definitions as provided by glew.h or GL.h. Others have tried to deal with this and encountered similar problems (e.g. [GLEW and Qt5 redefinition of headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123100/glew-and-qt5-redefinition-of-headers)). The workaround that got it going for me was to avoid including GL.h/glew.h and any Qt header related to OpenGL in the same file.